# Datainputstream and readUTF have data lost

Tags: java, json, datainputstream

I'm using java and received some json string from a server. I received json strings with readUTF but there is some data lost. I didn't received first two character of the every json packet.
Another problem is there is delay to received json strings. For example server sent one json string and client could not received it until approximately 50 json strings sent by server and client shows all the json strings suddenly.
What is the main problems?

```
public void run() {
    System.out.println("hi from thread" + id);
    try {
        clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.1.22", id);
        output = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        input = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        inputLine = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(System.in));
    } 
    catch( IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    String responseLine;
    try{      
        while(true){
            output.println( id + " ");
            System.out.println("sent:" + id + " ");
            responseLine = input.readUTF();
            System.out.println("received: " + responseLine);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Because of server send data with UTF format, so I cannot receive them with Bufferedreader

Comment: You should show us the code. But I can say, that it is likely that your problem is the usage of DataInputStream and readUTF(). Read the [DataInput.readUTF](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readUTF--) docs carefully. The first two bytes are interpreted as the number of bytes to read. Is this really what you want? Does the sender really create the bytes this way?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem before with applications like this, the main cause is DataInputStream which expects input to be in a certain format which I assume is not being conformed to by the server, try using BufferedReader instead as so:

```java
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
```

Then whenever you wish to read data just use

```java
some_string_here = input.readLine();
```

Note this requires each data value sent to end with a end line character "\n" or "\r".

Comment: Or `\r` or `\r\n`, and it's not an escape character, it's a line terminator.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on the default character set in the InputStreamReader constructor. The default charset is platform specific (e.g. Windows ANSI for Windows and UTF-8 for Linux). It is better to use the constructor with an explicit charset.

Comment: Unfortunately with readline, I cannot received any data but with readutf I can.

Comment: But readUTF() expects the data in a specific format. It is not helpful. If you have plain UTF-8 then you should wrap the InputStream with an InputStreamReader with explicit UTF-8 encoding and this with a BufferedReader. This is the way to go. This works, I did it several times. If this doesn't work for you, you should show us your adjusted code, so we can look for a bug.